# O que acontece se eu não especificar os { }?

Tags: php, sintaxe, estilo-de-codificação

Eu possuo este código que funciona normalmente:

```
if($time <= time()) {       
     if($time != 0)
         $Server->wsSend(1, 'perfect world');

        foreach ( $Server->wsClients as $id => $client ) 
            $time = time() + $adminMessage['interval'];
}
```

Não consigo modificá-lo porque ele não especifica os `{}` do `if` nem do `foreach`. Se eu colocar `{ }` no `foreach` o `wsSend` já não funciona.

Por que ele está funcionando?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## O motivo para o problema existir em PHP

Como C se tornou uma linguagem extremamente popular, e para ter sucesso, outras procuram copiar a sua sintaxe, como é o caso do PHP.

## O problema

Este é o chamado [***dangling else***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_else). Tecnicamente você não está usando um `else` mas o problema é essencialmente o mesmo. Esse é um problema criado pela forma que a linguagem C decidiu a sintaxe do `if`, onde você pode ter ou uma linha lógica única de execução ou um bloco de execução.

Se precisa executar apenas uma linha basta colocar essa linha logo após a condição. Pode ser colocado na mesma linha física do `if` ou depois, o que vai determinar que terminou é o ponto e vírgula.

Se precisar de um bloco de execução é necessário delimitá-los explicitamente através das chaves. Desta forma pode colocar quantas linhas (ou seja, quantos ponto e vírgulas) quiser dentro do bloco, o que vai determinar o seu fim é o "fecha chave".

Embora pareça uma boa ideia economizar digitação e tornar o código ligeiramente mais conciso quando tem apenas uma linha, é muito comum perder-se no controle disto e acabar criando uma lógica indesejada. Isto ocorre quando o programador planeja que vai ter uma linha e acaba precisando colocar mais que uma. Aí ele esquece que as chaves se tornam obrigatórias.

Indentação não conta nada para determinar o que será executado, ela serve apenas para o programador visualizar melhor o que está fazendo. Então seu código no fundo deveria ser indentado assim (o que provavelmente faria perceber o erro):

```
if ($time <= time()) {       
     if ($time != 0)
         $Server->wsSend(1, 'perfect world');
     foreach ( $Server->wsClients as $id => $client ) 
         $time = time() + $adminMessage['interval'];
}
```

Ou para visualizar melhor:

```
if ($time <= time()) {       
     if ($time != 0) {
         $Server->wsSend(1, 'perfect world');
     }
     foreach ( $Server->wsClients as $id => $client ) {
         $time = time() + $adminMessage['interval'];
     }
}
```

Assim claramente o `foreach` não está dentro do `if`. Se a sua intenção era que ele estivesse, a única solução seria:

```
if ($time <= time()) {       
     if ($time != 0) {
         $Server->wsSend(1, 'perfect world');
         foreach ( $Server->wsClients as $id => $client ) 
             $time = time() + $adminMessage['interval'];
     }
}
```

Eu faria melhor ainda:

```
if ($time <= time()) {       
     if ($time != 0) {
         $Server->wsSend(1, 'perfect world');
         foreach ( $Server->wsClients as $id => $client ) {
             $time = time() + $adminMessage['interval'];
         }
     }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Syntax/BracesIf.php).

## A solução

Só porque pode, não quer dizer que você deve evitar as chaves quando tem apenas uma linha. Mantendo o padrão de sempre usar as chaves, independente se é necessário ou não, você evita estes erros indesejáveis.

Uma alternativa é usar tudo na mesma linha, aí não tem confusão com o bloco.

Answer (score 5):

Cada `if` ou `foreach` que não vier acompanhado das chaves (`{` e `}`) levará em conta apenas o próximo comando.

Assim, o código que você postou equivale ao trecho de código abaixo:

```
if ($time <= time()) {       
    if ($time != 0) {
        $Server->wsSend(1, 'perfect world');
    }
    foreach ($Server->wsClients as $id => $client) {
        $time = time() + $adminMessage['interval'];
    }
}
```