# For sem o uso de chave

Tags: c, loop, for

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main ( void ){
    int row;
    int column;
    for ( row = 1; row <= 7; row++ ){
        for (column = 1; column <= row; column++ )
            printf("*");
            printf("\n");
} printf("\n");
}
```

[image: Saída de dados]

Quero saber se o *loop* for pode ser usado sem `{` depois do seu argumento?

É possível traduzir este código para mim?  Pois vejo o *loop* saindo do primeiro `for`, verificando a condição do segundo e dando *print* depois disso ele vai adicionar em `column` e retornar para adicionar em `row` também  e ficando `row = 2` e `column = 2`, dessa forma irá dar mais um *print*.

O problema é que se for assim, esse segundo *loop* já não estaria de acordo com a figura já que o `printf` só é acionado quando `column <= row`.

Como funciona esse trecho de código?

O programa inicia e libera * como *output* porque `column <= row = TRUE` ( ambos são 1), depois **1** é adicionado à `column`, tornando `column < = row = FALSE`, o programa sai do *loop* interno e pula uma linha, adicionando **1 à row** e tornando novamente `column (2) <= row(2) = TRUE`, por causa disso o programa irá liberar mais um * na linha debaixo e depois disso irá adicionar +1 à `column` e tornar `olumn(3) <= row(2) = FALSE`, fazendo com que saia do *loop* interno e vá para o loop externo.

Com esse pensamento eu estou imaginando que irá se formar *uma fileira vertical* de * já que `column` está apenas -1 que `row`, sempre, quando esse -1 deixa de existir com o incremento do *loop* interno, uma linha é adicionada pelo *loop* externo, dessa forma, não chega nem a formar o padrão.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primeiro vamos organizar o código para ficar fácil entender:

```
int main(void) {
    int row;
    int column;
    for (row = 1; row <= 7; row++) {
        for (column = 1; column <= row; column++)
            printf("*");
        printf("\n");
    }
```

Talvez por não estar indentado corretamente deu a entender outra coisa.

Podemos simplificar declarando a variável no próprio laço:

```
int main(void) {
    for (int row = 1; row <= 7; row++) {
        for (int column = 1; column <= row; column++)
            printf("*"); //isso pertence ao for interno
        printf("\n"); //isso já é só do for externo
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

E sim, o bloco de comando não precisam de chave se ele for composto de apenas um comando (*statement*). Um *statement* pode estar em uma linha, pode não ter linha própria, ou ter várias linhas (ele só termina com o `;` ou outra forma que indica o seu fim, como o fechamento de chave, por exemplo. Veja outra forma:

```
int main(void) {
    for (int row = 1; row <= 7; row++) {
        for (int column = 1; column <= row; column++) printf("*"); //for interno
        printf("\n"); //isso já é só do for externo
    } //está encerrando o statement do for externo
    printf("\n");
}
```

É horrível, mas isto funciona também:

```
int 
main
(void) {
    for (
        int row = 1;
        row <= 7;
        row++) {
            for (int column = 1;
                column <= row;
                column++)
                    printf("*"); //isso pertence ao for interno
            printf("\n"); //isso já é só do for externo
    }
    printf
    ("\n")
    ;
}
```

Ou pior ainda:

```
int 
main
(void) {
for (
int row 
= 1;
row <=
 7;
row++
) {
for (int column = 1;
column <= row;
column
++)
printf("*"); //isso pertence ao for interno
printf("\n"); //isso já é só do for externo
}
printf
("\n")
;
}
```

Há quem goste de fazer isto. Eu não gosto, gera confusão, uma manutenção pode criar um *bug* facilmente se o programador for descuidado. É fácil deixar o *statement* "manco", principalmente quando o bloco passar ter mais de uma "linha" durante a manutenção. Sem a chave, só uma "linha" faz parte do bloco.

Eu prefiro de forma mais clara, mas é a mesma coisa. Acho que lendo assim, ficará claro de cara:

```
int main(void) {
    for (int row = 1; row <= 7; row++) {
        for (int column = 1; column <= row; column++) {
            printf("*");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Por fim, eu começaria do 0. Não precisa, mas muita coisa vai começar do 0, acostume-se.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    //na primeira passada declara e atribui valor 0 para row
    for (int row = 0; row < 7; row++) { //em cada passada incrementa row e testa se é menor que 7
        //faz o mesmo aqui, vai entrar e ficar até a condição ficar falsa
        for (int column = 0; column < row; column++) { //o segredo é que cada entrada aqui row está um número maior
            printf("*");
        } //quando sair do laço vai executar a linha abaixo
        printf("\n");
    } //e vai tentar repetir o laço
    printf("\n");
}
```

Veja [funcionando igual ao seu no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/icKOHL). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/shadozvt-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/Pyramid3.c).

Faça um [teste de mesa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/136393/101).

A sua explicação está difícil de entender, então nem vou comentar sobre ela.

Leia [O que acontece se eu não especificar os { }?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/54413/101). É outra linguagem, mas vale igual.

Comment: Programa inicia. column < row = FALSE, programa pula uma linha, à row é adicionado 1. column < row = TRUE, programa libera (*) como print, à column é adiconado 1, column < row = FALSE, programa pula uma linha, à row é adicionado 1. column (1) < row (2) = TRUE, programa libera (*) como print, 1 é adicionado à column tornando column < row = FALSE, programa pula mais uma linha, row é adicionado mais 1. 


Percebeu o problema da forma que estou enxergando?  dessa forma o column será sempre um valor a mais que o row e se isso for dessa forma até agora ficaria 
*
*
*

Comment: dentro do () é para ser * e os dois ultimos * * * é na vertical

Comment: CARA! tava quebrando a cabeça aqui, mas acho que talvez seja essa o motivo de eu não estar entendendo: o valor de column depois de incrementado em +1 dentro do loop até que a condição seja falsa é, depois de sair do loop, resetado né?

Comment: Me desculpe, mas é muito difícil entender as coisas que você escreve, é quase cifrado, parece que você quer resumir tanto que come pedaços importantes. Talvez isso ocorra também com o seu entendimento. O que você descreveu não faz o menor sentido, tanto que eu não sei nem por onde começar para dizer o que está errado.

Comment: Acho que descobri onde eu tava errando. Eu pensava que o valor incrementado à variavél column era salvo dentro do loop, e por isso não daria certo. Mas o código funciona justamente pq quando eu saio do loop interno e vou para o externo o valor de column volta a ser 0.
de qualquer forma você me ajudou pq me mostrou um código mais arrumado e tirou duvidas em relação ao uso do FOR, além de dar dicas de teste. Obrigado.