# Erro no uso do else

Tags: c, string, if, else

O programa está dando um erro na hora de compilar.

> else without a previous if

Alguma coisa sobre o `else`, tem algo de errado com a condição `if` e `else`?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char est_civil;

    printf("Digite seu estado civil: ");
    est_civil = getchar();

    if (est_civil == 'C' || est_civil == 'c');
        printf("Casado");
    else

        if (est_civil == 'S' || est_civil == 's');
            printf("Solteiro");
        else

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

1. Os `if`s **não devem ter um ponto-e-vírgula** no final
2. O segundo `else` tá vazio. Precisa ser removido.

O código ainda pode ser simplificado, mas os erros de sintaxe são estes.

A única coisa que eu acho importante mudar é usar um `else if` ao invés de criar um bloco `else` com `if` dentro. Isso aumenta um tanto a legibilidade do código, talvez seja interessante ver [esta publicação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/13890/18246)<sup>*</sup>.

Algo como:

```
if (est_civil == 'C' || est_civil == 'c')
    printf("Casado");
else if (est_civil == 'S' || est_civil == 's')
    printf("Solteiro");
```

Código corrigido.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char est_civil;

    printf("Digite seu estado civil: ");
    est_civil = getchar();

    if (est_civil == 'C' || est_civil == 'c')
        printf("Casado");
    else if (est_civil == 'S' || est_civil == 's')
        printf("Solteiro");

    return 0;
}
```

<sup>*</sup>[Como escrever um código legível e de fácil manutenção?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/13890/18246)

Comment: Consegui, dei mole porque botei ponto e virgula na condição if e else, e isso não existe haha. Agora rodou o programa.

Comment: Pelo que você está dizendo, parece ser o caso de [marcar uma resposta como aceita](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/). Aqui não escrevemos "resolvido" na questão. Se tem uma resposta que realmente te ajudou, marque-a como aceita. Se chegou sozinho à solução, poste a solução como resposta. Assim o conteúdo fica mais organizado e fácil de ser encontrado futuramente por outras pessoas com problemas parecidos.

Comment: voce sabe que "usar else if" e "criar um bloco else com um if dentro" são exatametne a mesma coisa, não é?

Comment: Sim, por isso que eu falei que eu mudaria. Por que? Isso não ficou claro?

Answer (score 2):

Assim funciona, e bem mais simples, não?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("Digite seu estado civil: ");
    char est_civil = getchar();
    if (est_civil == 'C' || est_civil == 'c') {
        printf("Casado");
    } else if (est_civil == 'S' || est_civil == 's') {
        printf("Solteiro");
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/zbQqwJ). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/jyxkjnok-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/C/Syntax/DanglingElse.c).

Nunca deixe de colocar chaves no `if`, a não ser que saiba o que está fazendo, o que depende de bastante experiência. Especialmente não coloque o `;` no final da condição do `if` porque está encerrando ele e nada mais será executado como parte do seu bloco, ele se torna inócuo a não ser por efeito colateral, o que é avançado para seu estágio, e quase ninguém usa isso mesmo quando pode fazer algum sentido.

O `if` é um bloco de comandos. Blocos devem ser colocados entre chaves. Mesmo que eventualmente elas possam ser omitidas, e há casos que podem, por isso o compilador não impede, não deve fazer isto para evitar erros inesperados. Sem as chaves você incorre em [*dangling else*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_else).

Quando não tem nada para fazer em um `else`, não o use. Quando o que tem que fazer logo em seguida a um `else` a não ser um `if`, faça um `else if` e crie um bloco só.

Veja mais em [O que acontece se eu não especificar os { }?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/54413/101).